# How to avoid blocking my app without the use of background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Once a week I need to do 200 HTTP requests to a web service from my Rails app.

Each request takes 1 second in average, i.e. around 3 minutes in total if done all in a row.

The app has around 5,000 visits per day, so it's not very heavy in traffic. But I don't want to block my Rails app for 3 minutes though while doing these 200 requests.

A natural way to avoid this would be to use a background jobs tool.

Is there any other technique that could be used for the above scenario? E.g. schedule the requests with 10 second delays after each?

Comment: Just to understand: with tools like DelayedJob and Resque, is there a particular reason you *don't* want to use a background job?

Comment: I know those is the most straight forward and logical tool to use here. But I was thinking that my use case was so limited that engaging background process would be a bit over the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

Since a web server "can't speak until spoken to", you can create a RESTful interface to process your web service requests.  Then, create up a Javascript based *client* that triggers one request at a time and delays for a bit before triggering the next.  Fire up the client with a cron job on the machine of your choice, and run it until all 200 requests are serviced.